# Is automated testing of Android soft keyboards/input method UI possible?

Tags: android, robotium

I would like to create a test (similar to a robotium/selenium test) to test my keyboard service's layout in it's different configurations.

As the keyboard runs as a service, robotium cannot directly test it. Instead, I created an activity within the service to test the keyboard. The keyboard runs in a separate window, so robotium cannot see it's views.

My question is: is there a framework capable of testing input methods?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Can't be certain, but you may want to try out the capabilities of Nativedriver (http://code.google.com/p/nativedriver/), which I have found has a bit more flexibility than Robotium, though a bit harder to setup.

1. You do need to have the `server-instrumentation.jar` library included in your app and a few other necessities as outlined here: http://code.google.com/p/nativedriver/wiki/AndroidMakeAnAppTestable.  You can easily fork the server-instrumentation code to add more richness to its capabilities.  I found myself doing this for simple things like making it easier to find text boxes by their hints rather than by resource id.  **If you find that the built-in capabilities do not allow the testing of your keyboard, this is the place to add that capability,** and then commit the code for all of us!
2. I like a lot how the Nativedriver approach just uses a vanilla JUnit test rather than Android JUnit test, giving you a host of other tools that work well with JUnit (e.g. the java port for Cucumber) but don't fit in well with the Android JUnit test model.
3. You may find as I did that the fact that the activity is not killed at the end of a Nativedriver-based JUnit test case is nice, especially when you are in the middle of writing a test and are trying to remember what to do next in your UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to press the location as this is a bitmap displayed. This is more like what you develop the method UI.